# how to understand the magento 2 any module work flow and architecture

Tags: magento2

I need to understand any module workflow and architecture in magento2. what are steps involved in this process. which file is entry point? I think it is basic question but I must to know the work flow of modules.

Answer (score 1):

Below are some links of the guides which can help you to understand the workflow of the Magento modules.

> https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-module-in-magento-2/
>
> https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/
>
> https://www.mconnectmedia.com/blog/understanding-magento-module-structure-and-code-execution/

Hope it helps to start your journey with Magento 2 modules :)

Comment: thanks for your reply.